# Mixture of two normal distirbutions

Tags: probability, statistics

Say $X \sim N(0, 1), Y \sim N(0, 4)$. I flip a fair coin and set $Z$ to either $X$ or $Y$ with probability $0.50$. How can I compute the pdf and cdf of $Z$?

I computed

$$F_{Z}(z) = \frac{1}{2}(F_{X}(z) + F_{Y}(z)) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{z} \exp(-t^2) \mathop{dt}\right] + \frac{1}{2}\left[\int_{-\infty}^{z} \exp(-t^2/4)\right],$$

and I guess we can differentiate to get $f_{Z}(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(f_{X}(z) + f_{Y}(z)\right)$,

but is there some nice form that this can be written as? In particular, I know that we're given $N(0, 1)$ and $N(0, 4)$ distributions. Can I say something more specific about $Z$? I can't find any results online

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are looking for. You already have a closed-form pdf; how much nicer would you like it to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget the normalizing constant when you write down the pdf.

That is $f_X(z) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{z^2}2 \right)$ and $f_Y(z) = \frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left(-\frac{z^2}8 \right)$

For the CDF, you can use the standard normal CDF function $\Phi$ to write them as

$$F_Z(z) = \frac12 \Phi(z) + \frac12 \Phi\left( \frac{z}{2}\right).$$